# Checkpoint and restore the heap in Ruby

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, callcc

Ruby's `callcc` captures the current continuation, which can be subsequently called to restore the control, but not the data. I would like to capture the current continuation along with the current image of the memory.

It seems to me that capturing the heap shouldn't be very difficult; I can rely on `ObjectSpace::each_object` and `ObjectSpace::dump_all`, or `Marshal.dump`, or simply `Object.clone`. However, I don't see any straightforward way to restore the heap. Ideally, I would like to traverse the `object_id -> object`  map, restoring the old image of the object for every `object_id` (and re-adding the `object_id` if the corresponding object had been GC'd). Unsurprisingly, there is no Ruby-level api that lets me do this. I am wondering if there are any low-level hooks to Ruby's GC that I can use.

Any help is appreciated, including suggestions about alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, `Process.fork` can be used to more-or-less achieve the effect of heap checkpointing and restoration. Whenever I have to checkpoint the heap, I fork a new process and let the child continue. The parent process now contains the checkpointed heap:

```
def checkpoint
  if Process.fork.nil? then # if child, then resume execution immediately
    return
  else # if parent, wait for the child to exit.
    Process.wait 
  end
  return # Parent now resumes execution from state it was in before forking.  
end
```

When state has to be restored, child process simply exits:

```
def restore
  Process.exit
end
```

I am currently using this solution, and haven't encountered any problems so far. I will edit this answer if I find any in the future.

Answer (score 0):

How about pushing each on to a stack? Then you can keep popping off the stack to retrieve the data.

https://github.com/bvsatyaram/Ruby-Data-Structures